# Can anyone identify this type of connector?

Tags: connector, identification

My Sony CMT-X5CD (CD/DAB hifi soundbar thing) uses a very non-standard antenna connector, as shown in the photos. Can anyone identify it? It's used for the aerial(but unfortunately, the aerial supplied is absolutely terrible..) 2pence coin for scale (26mm dia) about the same size as a $1 American coin).

[image: Connector image]
[image: Connector image]
[image: Connector image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do the pins line up with an 0.1inch pitch header? What shape are the pins it connects to? A photo of the mating half may help

Comment: I will endeavour to get a photo of the pins this evening. At a guess they're probably 2mm apart or whatever is standard for PCBs - the connector looks like it was done on the cheap (otherwise it would have been a nice BNC or something..)

Comment: That looks like a JST connector.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it to be TE Connectivity, PN: [1470222-3](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1470222-3/1470222-3-ND/1890648)

Open the datasheet and verify the pitch and other measurements.

Comment: This looks spot on.. I'll have to measure up but it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Molex 3 pin connector? It looks a bit small though...

http://www.surplusgizmos.com/Molex-Style-3-Pin-Locking-Connector-w18-AWG-Wire_p_2516.html

Comment: I'm familiar with molex connectors, I think they're way too big for what this is. It does look like a JST connector but I'll need to actually measure things to confirm I think.

Comment: That connector you linked is NOT the same type as the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a connector that looks very similar to this. Look at the 3pin cable/connector for the Dynamixel servo motors from Robotis, here is a link http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/200mm-3-pin-dynamixel-compatible-cables-10-pack. Or google "3 pin cable dynamixel robotis".

Unfortunately, I can't find the name of such connector but perhaps contacting a supplier may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the very small aerial/antenna connector plug used in Sony DAB/FM radios and probably in others too. Having problems with DAB and sometimes FM radio reception with these aerials is very common. Molex manufactures them in this size as the OP in this useful post on [digital spy forums verifies](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1370738&page=2) The post shows how the connections work. Also [here is a link](http://www.aerialsandtv.com/fmanddabradio.html#RadioBands) to an informative radio and TV aerials site.

Essentially you need to connect the black wire in your plug to the centre wire of a 75 ohm co-axial cable either directly or via a co-ax connector. You can then attach to a basic FM aerial (half-wave dipole) for decent reception on FM & DAB, or to a DAB folded dipole for better DAB but worse FM. These aerials are best positioned vertically as described in the 2nd link.

Hope this is useful for some folks. It took me a while to get the bottom of the DAB reception problems we have here.